# Need a solution to execute python code, ".py", in the sh environment

Tags: python, sh

I would like to execute a circleCN.py python script by using #!/bin/sh.

I have searched the internet, found some suggestions, and none work. I get permission denied, and I changed my chmod of circleCN.py with a+x, I get invalid syntax, or I get another error. I have tried . /path/circleCN.py, exec /path/circleCN.py, python -c "/path/circleCN.py" and none work.
I have also tried to change #!/bin/sh to #!/usr/bin/env python and had no success. I would like to keep #!/bin/sh though.

I am very new to shell programming. I am also new to Linux.

When OpenFOAM users write Allrun or Allclean scripts, they use the #!/bin/sh shebang. I am working on an automation script and I would like to conform to the standard.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to execute python script under a bash shebang?
You can invoke python script inside the shell script like this

```
#!/bin/sh
python /path_to_file/circleCN.py
```

Comment: I am using OpenFOAM. Most scripts seem to be done with sh shebang. I would like to follow the standard.

Comment: ok. it's pretty common practice to do what I described in the answer.

Comment: you can 

1. implement the same logic of your python script in bash
2. invoke the python script in your bash script like I describe above